# Setup Google Tag Manager in Angular application

Tags: angular

When we are trying to implement GTM (Google Tag Manager) code in our Angular Universal application, we are facing following challenges:

The  tag changes include some JQuery parameters/fields which are not working in Angular and giving us errors and those errors are running in infinite loop. The error is related to $ not defined. As per the requirements we are not allowed to use JQuery library.
In the  tag changes  throwing us error related not supporting items in .
please help me out

Getting errors like this ->
(494)Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
VM725:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

We tried

`window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);} gtag('js', new Date()); gtag('config', 'MEASUREMENT-ID');`

but not working as expected.

Comment: Please put your diagnostics as text in the question, rather than images - that helps others to help you.

Comment: How did You include GTM? Did you use libraries such as ngx-google-tag-manager?

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary. All you need [is this](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/index.html#L54-L72) + [configure GTM to send `HistoryChange` events to GA](https://medium.com/@pieterjandeclippel/angular-or-react-or-whatever-and-google-analytics-97342c909e61)